# Properties as initial values received from parent, then copied into state? Or not using state, but always read from store?

Tags: reactjs, flux

**Context**

Being rather new to React/Flux, I sometimes find myself in the situation where my React component is receiving a value (say, for a float parameter shown in a text box) from a parent component via its properties. This happens in the render call of the parent component, that gets the value from the store and passes it on to the child component via its properties.

Then, when the user changes the value in the GUI (in the child component with the text box), this will cause a Flux action to be sent to the dispatcher with as payload the changed value. The dispatcher then calls the stores via the registered callbacks, which update their data using the new value. The stores then emit a change event, and the subcomponent is notified that the store has changed. The subcomponent grabs the new value from the store, and needs to trigger a re-render by calling setState, where the new state contains the new value. In order for this to work, I need to have a float field in the state of the subcomponent for my parameter, so that React can compare the old state with the new state.

In the constructor of the subcomponent, I copy the initial parameter value (coming in from the parent component) into the initial state. 
This feels a bit strange though...

**Proposal**

Another way could be to not use state at all, and always read everything from the store in the render function, but then there is no state left that React could check to see if a re-render is required? And calling forceUpdate also seems a bit harsh...

*Are there better ways to do this?*

Answer (score 0):

Setting state from props is an antipattern you should avoid when possible. Also, force re-rendering shouldn't be necessary in this case.

If your parent component is notified about the change in the store, it also passes down this value to sub-component, which is then re-rendered automatically. In the sub component you should be only getting value from this.props and also calling a callback passed as prop from parent component, when input changes. The parent component then dispatches an action, since it knows about the store in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I guess I was mixing component-local functionality with functionality that could be done in the parent component. And using a callback passed as a prop was something I was missing too. That way the child component  doesn't need to get its data to display from the store directly.Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

> I need to have a float field in the state of the subcomponent for my parameter, so that React can compare the old state with the new state.

I think this is where your misunderstanding lies.

React doesn't compare states in order to determine if it should rerender.  Rather, when it receives new states or props, it triggers it's render function internally, without posting any results to the display.  After completing this virtual-render, it compares the result of the render function with the currently displayed render.

What is being compared are the render results, not the state or props.  As a result, you can absolutely add/remove items from your state (via `this.setState`) and see the impact in your dom.

So at the end of the day, to solve your problem specifically, I would send your data from Store -> ParentComponent.state -> ChildComponent.prop.  You can rely on the updated Parent.state to trigger a rerender on that level, and then the resulting updated Child.prop to trigger the rerender on that level.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So, setting the state on the parent component is what I'll do, and then use the new state to update the prop(s) of my child components.